# Apply sorting of table in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, html-table, thymeleaf

I want to do initial sorting on first column in a  (using Thymeleaf) where i lookup the value in a message file. That means that the sort order can differ per country, which is what I want. Can I achieve that in html and Thymeleaf or do I have to look up the translation first before letting Thymeleaf iterate my data to create the table?

```
<table>
     <tr th:each="object : ${objects}">
          <td th:text="#{${#strings.concat('messagekeyprefix.', object.name)}}"></td>
          <td th:text="{object.value}"></td>
     <tr>
</table>
```

And in the different message.properties files I have the translations

```
messagekeyprefix.name1 = Xyz
messagekeyprefix.name2 = Def
messagekeyprefix.name3 = Abc
```

Using the above code will present the rows in the order of the "objects". But I would like to, maybe with dialect or something, do initial sorting on first column and it should be sorted on the translated names (so order can different between countries).

Comment: Do you want this to be automatically sorted on page load or interactivelly sorted by user?

Comment: Only on page load, no user interaction.

Comment: Why not have it sorted in POJO/Controller before it hits View? It will be much easier and efficient to do it that way since its on page load.

Comment: But than I can't use th:text in each iteration to look up the actual translation (only then will I know the actual name of the value in local language), I'll haveto do the lookup in message file before (in POJO or Controller) and I was looking for a way to avoid that.

Comment: What iteration? You advise that it loads once, which means you do lookup as part of post before you display it in view. Are you able to show your code? Or provide example of what you trying to achieve

Comment: I've updated the question with code and (hopefully) clarified my problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64469/discussion-between-aeseir-and-per-jansson).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per conversation and information provided, no Thymeleaf doesn't have sorting capability at this stage, and I doubt it will in near future.

Your best option is to have POJO read your file, and based on specifications in file actually sort either at database query level (best) or at object level (good).